# How to use storeAttribute in Selenium RC

Tags: selenium

I need to use `waitForAttribute()` - but I am having issues getting the attribute I need, so looking for an example usage of `storeAttribute()` using PHP.

Sample DOM

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <a class="add"></a>
</div>
```

I want to get the class of the `<a>`

```
// $foo is null
$foo = $this->storeAttribute('css=div.sidebar@class');

// error: Element css=div.sidebar["class" not found
$foo = $this->storeAttribute('css=div.sidebar["class"]');
```

I'm currently using CSS selectors, but don't mind using XPath.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my strategy - for anyone else running into issues this is what I eventually moved to in order to get `waitForAttribute()` to work:

```
$this->waitForCondition("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().$('div.sidebar a').hasClass('remove')");
```